# Retag ecmascript-harmony into ecmascript-6?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process, tag-wiki

The tag [ecmascript-harmony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-harmony) appears to be related to the fact that [ecmascript-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6) is labeled as [ES6 Harmony in places or something or other](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#Versions).

A quick perusal of the questions appears to show a bunch of questions dual-tagged with 6 and harmony, and a few regarding Node.js that I am not proficient enough to establish a connection with whether it relates to ES-harmony or something else called harmony.

There's also the tag [ecma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecma) that I've found that seems to be disorganized as all heck that probably needs to be looked at.

Someone who is more familiar with ES6

Comment: May be make them synonyms?

Comment: @PM77-1 not enough rep to suggest ._. that is also possible though, if we have a JS expert

Comment: Related: [Desynonymize \[ecmascript\] tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60417/desynonymize-ecmascript-tag), [What should we do about \[ecmascript-harmony\]?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214276/what-should-we-do-about-ecmascript-harmony)

Comment: To cite [my previous observations](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214276), it's not clear from the ES Wiki whether "ECMAScript Harmony" means "the ES6 specification", or "a workshop for proposed features for the ES6 spec" or "whatever spec version is going to be published next" (e.g., "harmony" might mean ES7 in a few years), or "a workshop for proposed features for future ECMAScript specs." This will certainly become clearer soon, now that ES6 is feature-frozen and ES7 is building some small amount of momentum.

Comment: @apsillers I am not javascript-savvy enough to be able to tell the difference. If that is the case, then at the moment, the harmony tag is still being used concurrently with es6 questions when it should be related to the concept or guidelines of harmony <_<

Comment: Considering this problem has been known since Jan 13 '15, why has it still not been fixed? Why are [tag:ecmascript-harmony] and [tag:ecmascript-6] still not synonyms of each other? I can't think of a case where two tags are more obviously synonyms of each other than this particular case!

Answer (score 12):

Actually it seems that the entire family of *ecma* tags needs to be reviewed.

So far we have:

- [ecma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecma)
- [ecmascript-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-5)
- [ecmascript-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6)
- [ecmascript-harmony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-harmony)
- [ecma262](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecma262)
- [ecmascript-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-4)
- [ecmascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript)
- [es5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es5)
- [es7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es7)
- [es2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es2015)
- [es2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es2016)
- [ecmascript-2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-2015)
- [ecmascript-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-7)

I found at least one questionable *synonym* where "ecmascript" is redirected to "javascript".  They are not the same. One is a **specification** and another - one of the existing **implementations**.

Comment: Agreed. There seems to be some confusion going on as to what a synonym in this space actually means.

Comment: I know there is a difference between exmascript and javascript, but is the difference large enough to warrant distinct tags? If I'm curious about some language feature I want to use on a real browser, wouldn't the javascript tag be appropriate, even if the answer might turn out to be independent of the implementation but instead answerable just from the ecma standard?

Comment: @MvG My point is that `JavaScript` is not the *only* ecmascript-compliant language implementation. There are also `JScript`, `ActionScript`, and some others.

Comment: @PM77-1 _Officially_, "JavaScript" only refers to one implementation, but in practice, its use is a lot broader than that. Pretty much the only time people actually use the word "ecmascript" is when they are (a) talking about the history of ecmascript/JavaScript (b) actually participating in the creation of the spec, or (c) talking about specific versions of the spec. The first two are not likely to come up on SO very much. The last one could be served by version-specific ecmascript tags.

Comment: @JLRishe - I would agree about that `JScript` and `TypeScript` belong to JavaScript *family*.  I strongly doubt that `ActionScript` is considered by developers as such.

Comment: According to every source I can find on the matter, ECMAScript Harmony, ES6 Harmony, ECMAScript 6 and ECMAScript 2015 (6th Edition) are just different names of the same standard. As such, I believe [tag:ecmascript-harmony] should be a synonym of [tag:ecmascript-6], but I can't even propose this because of some weird rule involving "version specific tags" (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317305/whats-the-proper-procedure-when-finding-a-synonym-for-a-version-specific-tag)

Comment: @PM77-1 That's not the common usage. Google, Apple, and Microsoft all refer to ECMAScript as implemented in their browsers as "JavaScript"; see MSDN, Google Developers, or Apple Developers for many, many examples. The name "JScript" was only ever coined by Microsoft to avoid being sued by Sun, who owned the JavaScript trademark, and while I was a babe back then as far as I know the name was never widely used among web developers. It certainly isn't now. Yes, "JavaScript" can (confusingly) refer to Mozilla's implementation in particular, but it usually just refers to ECMAScript.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I'm a bit familiar with these :-)

- I'm regularly cleaning up [ecma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecma), there are no more JS questions in there.
- [ecma262](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecma262) should be made a synonym of [ecmascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript), that is, [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript). Unfortunately, this needs a mod<sup>1</sup>?!
- [ecmascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript) is a synonym of [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) already
- [ecmascript-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-4)<sup>2</sup>, [ecmascript-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-5), [ecmascript-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6) ([es6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es6)), [ecmascript-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-7) ([es7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es7)<sup>3</sup>) are tags for questions that focus on a feature introduced in the respective edition. They should not be used on questions that use a specific version but are about a general problem observable in multiple versions.
- [ecmascript-harmony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-harmony) is for questions about [features and proposals that are not yet settled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21582553/1048572). It's about any features drafted for future editions, that is, currently everything post-ES6. It doesn't need to be retagged, and typically appeared on questions also tagged ES6 or ES7. It can serve as a hint on existing posts that the feature in question was not yet final, and the currently specced behaviour might differ in details.

<sub>1: Getting "*Failed to propose synonym: Version specific synonyms can only be created by moderators*". Gold badge here!

2: Might be burninated as well. ES4 never came into existence. We've got 2 questions related to that fact and 4 on which the tag serves no purpose.

3: Should be made a synonym, but I've yet too few rep in the tag</sub>

Comment: According to every source I can find on the matter, ECMAScript Harmony, ES6 Harmony, ECMAScript 6 and ECMAScript 2015 (6th Edition) are just different names of the same standard. As such, I believe [tag:ecmascript-harmony] should be a synonym of [tag:ecmascript-6], but I can't even propose this because of some weird rule involving "version specific tags" (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317305/whats-the-proper-procedure-when-finding-a-synonym-for-a-version-specific-tag)

Comment: @JohnSlegers: No, really not. Did you look into the source I linked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21582553/1048572)?

Comment: If not liberal synonyms, "Harmony" and "ES-6" are at least close enough concepts to be tag synonyms. From Wikipedia : `There are six editions of ECMA-262 published. Work on version 6 of the standard, codenamed "Harmony", was finalized in June 2015.` - From the MDN : `Code-named "ES.next" or "Harmony", the first working draft (based on ECMAScript 5.1) was published on July 12, 2011 as "ES.next".` From Leanpub's Understanding Ecmascript 6 : `Work then began on ECMAScript Harmony, with ECMAScript 6 being the first standard released in this new “harmonious” spirit.` etc.

Comment: @JohnSlegers your final quote supports what Bergi is saying and undermines your own position. It says that ECMAScript 6 was the *first* standard published under the "ECMAScript Harmony" project. As I understand it, that means ECMAScript Harmony is an effort that spans all standards that have been or will be created since ECMAScript 5. Yes, it was originally used synonymously with ES-6, since after ES-5 was published ES-6 was the primary or perhaps only thing that the Harmony project was working on. But they're not synonyms *now*, and it would be confusing to handle the tags as if they were.

Comment: @MarkAmery : I updated my question. See my UPDATE at the bottom -> http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317305/whats-the-proper-procedure-when-finding-a-synonym-for-a-version-specific-tag/317325