# Rename [es6] to [es2015]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, retag-request

I'm not sure what the etiquette on Stack Overflow is for renaming tags, but since the recent finalization of the standard, *ECMAScript6* as it was called is now renamed *[ECMAScript 2015](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/)*.

Do the [es6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es6) and [ecmascript-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6) tags need to be renamed to reflect this change?

Comment: Meh, it's still the sixth edition of the standard. And ES2015 is the [Third International Conference on Enterprise Systems](http://www.es2015.org/).

Comment: Don't go editing that many questions, simply ask for a synonym.  Just like [es6] is now a synonym for [ecmascript-6].  I suppose the synonym should be [ecmascript-2015].  Or the other way around.

Comment: What ever is done, please don't use [es2015].

Comment: @HansPassant Wasn't planning to! Like I said, no idea what the etiquette is around tags as I don't mess with them generally. ECMAScript 2015 is the official name so seems like it should be the master. If [ecmascript-6] === [es6] I'm not sure why [ecmascript-2015] wouldn't === [es2015]. Seems no different than [visual-studio-2013] and [vs2013]

Comment: See also [this overview](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298512/1048572)

Comment: ES2015 is_not_ the official name. It's "ECME-262 6th Edition, The 2015 ECMAScript Language Specification".

Comment: I was apprehensive about posting this question because I thought it would turn into a discussion about the naming. @RayNicholus That's the title of the spec document. In section [1.0](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-scope) it clearly states the name of this iteration of the language. Maybe you're saying that *ES2015* specifically isn't the correct name, but then I never claimed it was :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think we need to do this. Everybody knows what ES6 is, and most people still talk about ES6 instead of ES2015. None of the two terms is wrong:

- ECMAScript 2015 Language
- sixth edition of the ECMAScript Language [Specification]

We might make a synonym if need arises, and might eventually swap the synonym direction. I don't think the time for that has come already, though.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. I'll still be using ES6/7 to reference it, simply because I find it easier to search than ES2015 - which I guess is another reason it should stay as-is.

Comment: I disagree. Quoting from the Introduction: "This Ecma Standard defines the **ECMAScript 2015 Language**. It is the **sixth edition** of the **ECMAScript Language Specification**." _(emphasis mine)_. According to that, the name of the language is **ECMAScript 2015**, not **ECMAScript 6** (or ES6).

Comment: @toothbrush: But ES5 never had been "ECMAScript 5" either - [it does define](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/) the "**ECMAScript language**", and officially was only "**Edition 5.1 of the ECMAScript Standard**" (ECMA-262). We still refer to it as ES5 (or ES5.1), just as we now do to edition six as ES6.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't make it right, does it? I'm not going to fight over this. If you think it's going to bring more confusion having the tags redirect to ECMAScript 2015, that's fine with me; I just thought it would prevent confusion.

Comment: @toothbrush: No, I don't see what's wrong with it. ES6 is just an abbreviation for *ECMAScript 6th Edition* (which might not be the official name, but is certainly right). Let's agree to disagree which one causes less confusion :-)

Comment: @Bergi Fine with me  :)

Comment: By the time we have ES9 or ES10 they might be back to simple numbering, just as MS Windows started with numbers, then went to years, then went to names, then finally went back to numbers. (And then skipped a number, because...well...9 is unlucky? I don't know.)