# Synonymize [ecmascript-6] and [ecmascript-2015]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

Let's synonymize [ecmascript-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6) and [ecmascript-2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-2015). I'm [not talking about renaming one of them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297774/rename-es6-to-es2015), a lot of people (and the spec) call it ECMAScript 2015, a lot of other people call it ECMAScript 6 (and it *is* the sixth edition of the spec), so there's value in having them both exist, but they're synonyms of each other. Doesn't matter which is master, [ecmascript-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6) or [ecmascript-2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-2015). That said, now that TC-39 is using years and [expecting to release an edition every year](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_about-es6.html), I predict we'll all start using them (e.g., for ES2016, ES2017, etc.).

Comment: If I remember correctly, suggesting a synonym requires the master to have at least 1/1.25 times as many questions as the slave. So [ecmascript-2015] must be the slave and [ecmascript-6] the master unless a mod does the opposite.

Comment: But the official name is "ECMAScript® 2015", not "ECMAScript® 6". Also, it would be better if we take care of "ECMAScript® 2016" now itself.

Comment: @Oriol There are no requirements for synonyms, at least not if a moderator creates them. I'd have expected the tag to be called [tag:javascript-es6], I know it's not the official name, but most of the time I see it called just Javascript ES6 or only ES6.

Comment: @thefourtheye Does ECMAScript release a new version every year?

Comment: @TylerH: Not historically, but [that's the idea now](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_about-es6.html): *"The plan is to release a new version of ECMAScript every year, with whatever features are ready at that time."* [Elsewhere](https://tc39.github.io/process-document/) they say they "may" propose new releases to the Ecma general committee in May and September (and!) but I think they expect no more than one per year, and they emphasize the word "may." :-)

Comment: @TylerH if that were the case, I would say *"just call it ecmascript, and call it a day"*

Comment: @Braiam: Well, we have a tag for that: [tag:javascript]. :-) The version-specific tags are for version-specific features, before, during, and immediately after.

Comment: The thing is that it reduces visibility sharply. Also, *one does not simply reinvent a language yearly!* People that know how to answer a 2015 question may know how to answer 2016 and beyond.

Comment: @Braiam: Not sure I'm following your logic, but TC-39 aren't reinventing JavaScript every year; they're *augmenting* it. Backward compatibility is *almost* never sacrificed, and there's only been one big one so far, which was opt-in (strict mode). So right now, for instance, in a [tag:ecmascript-2017] tag, we'd be talking about [asynchronous functions](https://github.com/tc39/ecmascript-asyncawait) and [the exponentiation operator](https://github.com/rwaldron/exponentiation-operator) and the like. Until recently we'd've been talking about `Object.observe`, but it's gone back to stage 2.

Comment: "Backward compatibility is almost never sacrificed," exactly my point! You are just adding features to something that essentially don't change in its core. Having a tag for each batch of added features is simply not worth the problems it causes (mistagging/irrelevant tagging, tag bombing, difficulty to find the relevant question, tag badges becomes essentially inaccessible for experts on the topic, etc.).

Comment: @Braiam: I'll have to respectfully disagree that ES5, ES2015, and (by the looks of it) ES2016 don't fundamentally change the core of JS. :-) ES2015 in particular is a revolution for the language -- or rather, a revolutionary *evolution*. ES5 gave us control over properties we could only dream of in ES3, and strict mode. Now ES2015 is giving us **dramatically** powerful new abstractions like arrow functions, generators, iterators, block scope, promises, templates, modules, and constants. It's like the Cambrian explosion. ES2016's async functions are similarly fundamental, if a bit lonely.

Comment: So, are you saying, that because to a plain donut I add chocolate cream and then later strawberry jam it stops being a donut?

Comment: @Braiam: No, that's why we have [tag:donut] (er, I mean [tag:javascript]), which should be and is the primary tag used. But when discussing the details of Donut 2015's nifty new chocolate cream, [tag:donut-2015] (*combined* with [tag:donut]) lets us be more specific. (And then, of course, [tag:donut-jumped-the-shark] when they add strawberry jam to a chocolate cream donut! ;-) )

Comment: @Braiam: But you can always post a request for the version-specific tags to be removed. Discussion of that off-topic for *this* request, which is a boring old "they're synonyms, let's make them synonyms" request.

Answer (score 4):

Yes please, make them synonyms.

I'll vote for [ecmascript-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6) as the master.

Comment: Why ES6 when the official name is ES2015?

Comment: @Pier-LucGendreau: It's not ES2015, and we surely won't name the tag "*ECMAScript-2015-Language*". ES6 is just what everyone knew and knows this particular revision, and I don't see any reason to break the pattern (ES3, ES5, ES5.1, ES6, ES7) *yet*. As soon as ES2016 launches and we stop using the term [tag:ecmascript-7] as well, we may consider renaming.

Comment: A *bit* hyperbolic there, "ECMAScript 2015" is clearly the name of this edition in the spec header (as well as "ECMA-262 6th Edition," yikes), and also the suggested tag name (`n.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '.')`) ;-) I really don't care whether the chicken or egg comes first, I just want to combine the tags.