# JavaScript version tags cleanup proposal

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonym-process

The JavaScript/ ECMAScript version tags could use a little tidying. It's a large family of tags, and there are a few stragglers that should be made to be synonyms to other existing tags, if not dealt with in other ways.

I'm proposing that the following, existing tags be synonymized:

- ⇆ [ecmascript-2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-2016)

  - Synonymize with [ecmascript-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-7)<sup>1</sup>
- ✅ [es2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es2017)

  - Synonymize with [ecmascript-2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-2017)
- ✅ [es2018](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es2018)

  - Synonymize with [ecmascript-2018](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-2018)
- ✅ [es2020](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es2020)

  - Synonymize with [ecmascript-2020](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-2020)

The tag [ecmascript-2021](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-2021) also exists, and at time of posting had only one, incorrectly-tagged question, but it has since been properly retagged.

None of these seem to be controversial changes, since they all follow precedents from other JS version tag synonyms, but I don't have the rep to formally suggest tag synonyms to the system, and wanted to open the door to dissent if it's there.

---

<sup>1</sup> - Maybe? All ECMA version tags prior to v7/ 2016 have the edition number as their parent tag, rather than the year. It's possible this should be flipped on v7, since both tags exist, but.

Comment: Isn't there a separate version for JavaScript? E.g. [JavaScript 1.8.5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.8.5) (released with [Firefox 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox_early_version_history#Firefox_4)) (2011-03-22), corresponding to some version of [ECMAScript 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#5th_Edition) (2009).

Comment: @Peter It looks like there *used* to be. [One level up](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript#JavaScript_versions) from the link you included has information about the JavaScript versions you mention, the last of which being 1.8.5, after which the versioning scheme was dropped in favor of ECMA-262 Editions, which is where modern JS versioning comes from.

Comment: The ECMAScript® 2015 Language Specification was originally known as ECMAScript 6th edition, but its name was changed, officially, to ECMAScript® 2015. Later versions were officially named for the year. You *could* refer to them as their other names, like ECMA-262 7th Edition *if you want to*, but it's not official. I think all ECMAScript versions 2015 and later should have the form `ecmascript-year`.

Comment: From a practical standpoint: it depends more on the host interpreter implementations than specific versions of the specification. I say get rid of it and users should prefer host tags instead (firefox, node, etc.)

Comment: @Braiam Each such host regularly upgrades their environment. Eg, you can count on all such hosts to, by now, have implemented nearly everything from ES2019 and before, and most things from ES2020. Except for IE, which never gets updated since it's EOL, the *year* (eg ES2020) is much more informative than the host.

Comment: @CertainPerformance yet, when I write javascript I only look at the host application, as do ~100000 times the askers (comparing the sum of all the questions with EmacScript tags vs Javascript + host tags). From a *practical* point of view, no, it doesn't matter at all.

Comment: @HereticMonkey The "ECMAScript® 2015 Language" is still officially specified by the 6th edition of the ECMAScript specification (ECMA-262), and similar for all the other editions. See also [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298513/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi, all of the versions of ECMAScript specification carry a numbered edition along with their year designation. And, as I say in my comment, you are free to refer to them as such. But the official name is ECMAScript 2015. Look in [the 2020 version of ECMAScript](https://tc39.es/ecma262/2020/) You will find *65 references to "ECMAScript 2015"*, but no references to ECMAScript 6 or ES6, one reference to "6th edition", and five references to the "sixth edition". And, while I do respect your experience in the matter, a reference to your own answer doesn't sway me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Synonyms added, approved, or verified

- [ecmascript-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-7) ➞ [ecmascript-2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-2016) <sup>1</sup>
- [es7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es7) ➞ [ecmascript-2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-2016) <sup>1</sup>
- [es2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es2016) ➞ [ecmascript-2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-2016)
- [es2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es2017) ➞ [ecmascript-2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-2017)
- [es2018](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es2018) ➞ [ecmascript-2018](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-2018)
- [es2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es2019) ➞ [ecmascript-2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-2019)
- [es2020](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es2020) ➞ [ecmascript-2020](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-2020)
- [es2021](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es2021) ➞ [ecmascript-2021](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-2021)

---

1. The question requested [ecmascript-2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-2016) ➞ [ecmascript-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-7). However, the [current draft of ecma262](https://tc39.es/ecma262/) explicitly says

   > ECMAScript 2016 was the first ECMAScript edition released under Ecma TC39's new yearly release cadence and open development process.

   As such, I went with [ecmascript-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-7) ➞ [ecmascript-2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-2016) and [es2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es2016) ➞ [ecmascript-2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-2016) (i.e. the opposite direction from what was "maybe" requested in the question). I'm willing to revisit this if there are notable arguments for continuing to use [ecmascript-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-7) as the primary tag for that revision. However, in general, we use the official name/version as the primary tag.

Answer (score 16):

No objection to the proposal other than I wonder if there's any point to the version-specific tags at all here in 2020 (soon to be 2021)...?

There was some purpose to the old "es6" tag back between 2009 (the 5 and then 5.1 specs) and 2015 (the 6th / 2015 spec): it identified things that were definitely going to be part of the upcoming "6th edition." But since the 2015 spec,¹ [the process](https://tc39.es/process-document/) has been fundamentally different: [Proposals](https://github.com/tc39/proposals) move through stages and it's only when they reach the "finished" stage — including having implementations in the wild — do they get merged into the living [editor's draft](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/). That draft, in turn, forms the basis of the annual snapshot that Ecma International formally adopts the following June.

So features are constantly underway, and it's really only at the very end that you have any clarity what "version" of the spec they'll be in — at which point, they're already part of the modern language. Sometimes a proposal moves quickly through the process (as with the logical assignment operators). Other times it can be years and years *(I'm looking at you, decorators)*.

Rather than version tags, if folks want a tag that identifies more specifically that a question relates to something new, a tag specific to the proposal you're asking about might be useful, rather than a tag related to a version of the specification.

---

¹ *(technically a bit before it, but ignore that)*

Comment: This has the same problem but looking from the future: once the proposal is merged, the  tag has no meaning other than "this question was about this proposal" which doesn't add any value once that proposal is accepted into the draft.

Comment: @Braiam - Tags identifying the thing the question about are standard. They continue to have value after the proposal is standardized. Consider the tag [optional-chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/optional-chaining+javascript), which allows expressions like `a = b?.c`. It still, now that the feature is standardized, marks that the question is specifically about optional chaining. The status of the proposal doesn't change the meaning of the tag. That's my point: The tag is about what the question is about, not the version of the language the feature the question asks about is.

Comment: Let it put it this way: that's as useful as a version tag, ie. not useful at all. Lets put ourself in a **practical** example: arrow functions. There are ~10k posts that references arrow functions with [javascript]. Of these, there are 807 non-closed questions that don't include the [feature] tag, and 0 that does since 20190101. Would you believe that in answered ratios, they are ~10% answered that [javascript] has? **There's no practical advantage why those should exist.** Just because it can be argued that questions could use a tag, doesn't mean that said tag should exist.

Comment: @Braiam - Well, okay. So you're proposing getting rid of *all* feature-specific tags (of which there are **hundreds**). That's a bold proposal I suggest you make separately. :-) I'm not sure whether I agree or disagree with it (certainly I've never seen any value in the [tag:function] tag, nor [tag:array]), but it's a separate question to this.

Comment: Are you sure that that's what I'm proposing? What I'm proposing is removing **useless tags**. There are no use for those since no one would ever have knowledge about those but not about the general language. Also, function and array are not "features" of a language, they are [concept tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/300700/792066). Do not mix them.