# Tag suggestion for ECMAScript Temporal

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

The [TC39](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecma_International#Committees) [Temporal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal) proposal adds (finally!) a modern date/time API to JavaScript. If all goes well, Temporal is planned to move to Stage 3 (which means browsers, TypeScript, etc. can start shipping it) in March 2021, which will prompt a lot more Stack Overflow questions about it starting just a few weeks from now.

As champions of this proposal, we'd like to proactively figure out the right Stack Overflow tag to use for questions about this new ECMAScript feature. Then we can add a tag wiki for it and promote this tag in the documentation and in GitHub issues to coalesce Q&A for this feature around one tag.

But we're not sure what's the right tag name to use.

- [`temporal`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/temporal) is one choice. It has 226 existing questions about various topics. In most cases this tag is used mostly as an adjective not to refer to a particular technology.
- `temporal-js`
- `js-temporal` - at this point this is my favorite because Temporal is a feature of JavaScript, not an add-on API or framework like [React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(web_framework)).
- `es-temporal` - this works best for purists who consider ECMAScript and JavaScript to be really different things, but I'm not sure the global Stack Overflow audience would discover it as easily because "es" (outside "ES6") isn't used as much as "js" as an abbreviation for the language.

Any suggestions for which of these would work best for discoverability and to avoid ambiguity? Is there a heuristic or best practices that can help pick the right Stack Overflow tag?

Also: if we did pick `temporal` then what's the right etiquette for existing questions on that tag?  Should we retag them or leave as-is?

Comment: There's also the possibility of `javascript-temporal`, spelling out the language might be good.

Comment: One possible pattern is also [tag:es6-promise], [tag:es6-class], [tag:es6-modules], etc., so the new tag would become [tag:es12-temporal] or [tag:es13-temporal]. But this pattern appears to have been abandoned after ES6.

Comment: @SebastianSimon I've [seen it said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401884/javascript-version-tags-cleanup-proposal#comment801105_401884) that those numerical version numbers aren't strictly "official" post-es6 anyway, and that year numbers are the preferred versioning system (eg. es2015). That said, I still see JS versions referred to as "esXX" moderately often... on a practical level they sure seem mostly interchangeable.

Comment: Are browsers, etc. ready and waiting to ship it or will they still have significant dev time to spend after March arrives?

Comment: @TylerH - The latter. The proposal has a large surface area so my guess is that the earliest we'll see it in browsers will be the end of the year. But Google is one of the sponsors of the proposal so it's likely that work will start relatively soon after Stage 3 approval.  Same for production-quality polyfills. A non-production polyfill already exists and I've heard significant interest from one of the other proposal sponsors to productionize the polyfill. So I think the fourth quarter of 2021 seems likely for either browsers or a production polyfill-- maybe both.

Comment: @SebastianSimon - ES6 is still a good identifier because it made so many big changes to the language, but the official naming is now ES20XX and few people use ESn above 6 as a result. The problem with something like es2022-temporal is that we're not really sure what year Temporal will make it into the official specification. Ideally would be 2022, but could be 2023 depending on speed of adoption and feedback.

Comment: I guess some standardization is needed around here indeed. *Intl* was tagged as [tag:ecmascript-intl], which to me sounds about right (yeah I'm one of the "purists"). There are many [javascript-\*](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript-*) but a lot of them are questionable. Finally there is [es6-\*](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/es6-*), which seem to be more into what we want here, but such a precise versioning seems like a wrong choice as it would change every year and ES6 features are still available in ES2021.

Comment: And I should have noted in the previous comment that [js-*](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/js-*) is almost only for libraries, I don't think we want that for features.

Comment: Do we really need another tag for this object api? Echoing @Kaiido reservations, I don't think we really need a tag for each global object of javascript just for having one. What's the need for it?

Comment: @Braiam I think it's exceedingly reasonable for there to be a tag for a new official datetime API. Dates and times are often a massive pain in any programming project, and having a tag to aggregate questions about these new features sounds really useful for bringing experts to such questions.

Comment: @Braiam - As @zcoop98 noted, tags can be helpful to attract experts. Also good for aspiring experts who want to make a name for themselves by helping others. Also, tags are widely used for .NET namespaces like `system.net`, `system.data`, etc. Sometimes individual .NET types like `system.data.datatable` also have tags. In non-.NET platforms, C++ `chrono` has a tag. C's `time.h` too. Why is this case different?

Comment: @zcoop98 that would make sense in a library that needs to categorize everything, Stack Overflow doesn't need to.

Comment: @JustinGrant that's a misguided approach. Experts would create the tags if they feel like, we don't need to preemptively do so. Heck, I've seen questions that 80% of the +10 answers were posted when the question had 1-2 tags, which later came to have 3 more tags attached just for the heck of it.

Comment: There still is no consensus on this, right? [Temporal in Chrome](//stackoverflow.com/q/59054444/4642212) is a question without any Temporal-related tag, [How to get Temporal.Duration from two Temporal.Instant in JavaScript?](//stackoverflow.com/q/66593473/4642212) is a question tagged with the [ambiguous](/q/296620/4642212) [tag:temporal] tag. Temporal didn’t make it into ES2021, but we’ll need consensus soon. Any of [tag:es-temporal], [tag:js-temporal], [tag:ecmascript-temporal], [tag:javascript-temporal] (no particular order) are fine to me.

Comment: Things have recently become even more confused, with the advent of the Temporal workflow engine, which is quickly gaining popularity. The correct tag for that one would be [temporal-workflow], but because [temporal] exists and has no wiki description, users sometime use that tag instead, feeling that this is appropriate.

Answer (score 14):

`[ecmascript-temporal]` sounds like the best choice to me, but this question reveals a need for some standardization in that area.

---

We already have [ecmascript-intl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-intl), for a similar case and it seems to work pretty well there. (There was a single question tagged [javascript-intl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-intl) but I just edited it out).

There are many [`[javascript-*]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript-%2A) tags, most of which are at least questionable, and the rest are just plain wrong. 
For instance, [javascript-events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-events) is in the process of being burninated by [Brian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4370109/brian-tompsett-%e6%b1%a4%e8%8e%b1%e6%81%a9) for years. If we consider "JavaScript" to mean the language, then there is no JavaScript Event, [except maybe that one](https://262.ecma-international.org/10.0/#sec-memory-model-fundamentals), Events as we know them in a web page are specified by the DOM standards ([WHATWG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WHATWG)). 
A similar situation exists with [javascript-audio-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-audio-api) for which I started a [synonym request](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/web-audio-api/synonyms) since that API is a Web API (W3C), and is not related at all with TC39.

The only ones in there that relate to an ECMAScript feature are [javascript-import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-import) and [javascript-decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-decorator), and I believe they'd be fine as a synonym of an `[ecmascript-...]` equivalent.

We also have a lot of [`[es6-*]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/es6-%2A) tags, which seem way cleaner, as they correctly do relate to ECMAScript features. However ES6, a.k.a ES2015, shipped in ... 2015. We're now at ES2020, and I guess the Temporal feature would land in ES2021. But who really cares Promises went out in 2015? We still have many questions today about Promises running in an ES2020 environment.

There is also the [`[js-*]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/js-%2A) tags, which seem to relate to specific libraries rather than language features.

I believe all these tags relating to ECMAScript features should be made synonyms of an `[ecmascript-...]` equivalent that has to be created, though I'm not sure how this should be coordinated.

Comment: *"But who really cares Promises went out in 2015"*. One could argue about *javascript* and *ecmascript* the same. Isn't it ultimate javascript at one time?

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt It's *always* ECMAScript. It's *sometimes* JavaScript (see, e.g., JScript, ActionScript, and [other implementations of ECMAScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ECMAScript_engines))

Comment: Regarding [[tag:javascript-import]], I think that should be synonymised to [[tag:es6-modules]]. (We also have [[tag:esm]] and [[tag:node-modules]], but I think those are separate).

Comment: @Bergi yes I agree, I thought about thos too when writing that answer. The `import` keyword/object may very well have its own questions, but I think indeed they'll still be find under the [es-import]. Though when I try to propose the synonym from my mobile, I have a "Version specific synonyms can only be created by moderators" error popping out... Do you face the same?

Comment: @Kaiido Yes, same error message

Comment: The Temporal champions team talked this over and we agreed that [ecmascript-temporal] sounds like the best tag to use. Consider it official! It's a good idea to make es-temporal and js-temporal and javascript-temporal synonyms for it. I'm hoping that my 42K rep will be enough to create tag synonyms! :-)

Comment: OK, I added a [Q&A pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72565356/in-javascript-what-is-the-correct-temporal-type-to-use-for-parsing-a-particul/72565357#72565357) to create the [ecmascript-temporal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-temporal) tag and filled in its [tag description and wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ecmascript-temporal/info).

Looks like I need 5 tag rep to suggest tag synonyms. Could I get an upvote on the Q&A pair linked above?

Answer (score -3):

I'm certainly fine with [ecmascript-temporal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-temporal), but would like to offer a counterproposal:
Simply combine [ecmascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript)+[temporal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/temporal). (Yes, ecmascript is a synonym for javascript<sup>1</sup>).

This is what we went with for years, and it's fine<sup>2</sup>. People asking about the JavaScript `Date` object tag their questions [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)+[date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/date), and it works. People asking about using promises in JavaScript tag their questions [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)+[promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/promise), even if we have a [es6-promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es6-promise) tag it's mostly used by people asking about details of specific ES6 promise specification - not their general usage.

I expect the same to happen for the new `Temporal` objects. People who are involved with the proposal or want to understand details of it will refer to it as specific they can, but once the new API becomes widespread in use questions will crop up that are only tagged [temporal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/temporal)+[js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/js). I don't think we can<sup>3</sup> or should try to prevent that.

<sub>1: the tag, I mean.

2: it doesn't work for everything, e.g. distinguishing modules into [es6-modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es6-modules) and [module-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/module-pattern), but for most.

3: blacklisting the tag doesn't seem like an option to me.</sub>

Comment: I could agree, if we had the tools to handle this correctly. The impossibility to follow a merge of two tags makes it a real pain for answerers who are only interested in that specific domain. For instance I sometimes want to find the questions about the web File API, for this I have to check for [file]+[js] and [blob]+[js] separately and manually. Without the [js] tag these contain so much noise it's almost impossible to find anything in there, and I'm pretty sure a lot of questions end up unanswered because askers didn't know that adding [js] to these was required to have someone see it.

Comment: @Kaiido Yes, not being able to follow tag combinations is a problem (but imo only a small one). Regarding questions that lack the [js] language tag, those usually get fixed quickly enough.

Comment: I think (after reading the tag excerpt) `date` or `promise` is referring to the concept, while `es6-modules`, `es6-temporal` referring to a specific API/Language Feature. So i think, every `es6-temporal` questions could be tagged `ecmascript` + `date`, but not vice versa. The same we would tag `SQL` just with `DateTime` instead of `DateTime2` implementation.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt Yes. Mostly I'm trying to say that most askers won't make this distinction though, and just enter the name of the API they're using (here: `temporal`) in the tag line.

Comment: I would argue against this solution, largely because "temporal" in this usage isn't as generic as the "date" or "promise" tags are. While "date" and "promise" stand on their own because they apply to a specific cross-language concept, "temporal" does not, because it *specifically* refers to this JS API. Put another way, [js]+[date] is as acceptable as [c#]+[date] is, but there is *only* [js]+[temporal], which to me says that "temporal" shouldn't be alone.

Comment: This is also besides the fact that [[tag:temporal]] already exists on 228 Qs, and its usage is *already* largely ambiguous.