# Should tag creators be able to suggest synonyms even if they lack 5 tag-answer score?

Tags: feature-request, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

Based on the [advice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405324/tag-suggestion-for-ecmascript-temporal) of experts here on Meta, I created the [ecmascript-temporal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-temporal) tag for the upcoming [ECMAScript Temporal API](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal), which is a new date/time API that will soon be available in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Node.js, etc.

Now that the tag is created, I'd like to create synonyms for this tag: [js-temporal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/js-temporal), [javascript-temporal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-temporal), and [es-temporal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es-temporal), discussed in the [Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405324/tag-suggestion-for-ecmascript-temporal) linked above.

But to make tag suggestions I'll need a "tag answer score" of 5. This requires (I assume?) 5 answers, and also requires waiting until [3:00 AM UTC](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269040/when-is-tag-score-calculated) for the batch job to run. These limits make a lot of sense for established tags.

But what about new tags? When a new tag is created, the tag creator may have a pretty good idea of needed synonyms. Should we allow synonym requests to be made at the same time? That way the tag creator doesn't have to set an alarm to remember to request the synonyms later, and also so tag creators who haven't answered many questions on that topic (which will be common for new technologies like Temporal, or when tags are created by different people than folks doing the bulk of the answering) can still make synonym suggestions.

Anyway, my feature request would be to enable the creators of tags to be able to make tag suggestions, even if they lack the 5-answer-score.

I'm not familiar with the history behind the tag suggestion limit (e.g. maybe synonyms have been abused in the past?) so my request may not make sense. But at least wanted to raise it here in case this suggestion is helpful to the community.

And in the meantime, could I get help from a mod to add these three synonyms (assuming these are welcome)? If it's better to create a new Meta post for that synonym request for mods, I'de be happy to do so. Just let me know. Thanks!

Comment: We don't *proactively* create synonyms; that's not how the tagging system is meant to work. Synonyms are created between tags that already exist.

Comment: And if one is needed (i.e. when the dupe tag exists), you write a [meta-tag:synonym-request] here on meta

Comment: "This requires (I assume?) 5 answers" - not necessarily, you can get one with a score of 5, or several with a score of less. But yeah, tag synonym system (and, frankly, everything about the systems governing tag management) is in dire need of rework. I heard a rumor SE's trying to do something about it, but it's 6 to 8 as usual.

Comment: As a quick FYI, we have a specific Markdown markup that will link and format tags properly automatically: `[tag:tagname]` and `[meta-tag:tagname]` for main and Meta tags respectively.

Comment: "*When a new tag is created, the tag creator may have a pretty good idea of needed synonyms.*" since [everyone with 1500 reps can create any tags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags), based on [observation](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new), not all of them have any slightest idea on how tags work.