# Make [es2020] a synonym of [ecmascript-2020]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

The versioning scheme for [ecmascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript) is [`ecmascript-year`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-*) for the versions above ES6.

However, [ecmascript-2020](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-2020) (11 questions) has a differently named variant, [es2020](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es2020) (with 22 questions!).

[ecmascript-2020](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-2020) follows the naming scheme and has a tag wiki, while [es2020](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es2020) does not; so I think the latter should be made into the synonym of the former ([es2020](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es2020) -> [ecmascript-2020](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-2020)).

I can't vote for this synonym creation, as I don't have any points in either tag (only their "parent", [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)).

Comment: While we're at it: [`[es2021]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es2021) -> [`[ecmascript-2021]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-2021)

Comment: @Ivar Oh, I didn't even realize! I've retagged that single question it had, but we'll have to keep an eye on it.

Comment: Related: [JavaScript version tags cleanup proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/401884) (or even duplicate? I proposed this exact synonym and a few others last October, but didn't get much traction. Maybe you'll have better luck.)

Comment: [List at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#History).

Comment: @zcoop98 Oh, yes, I see. It's the same, just that mine is one step, while yours is a bit bigger project. I read through your question, and I'm not sure why it reached a standstill (while I like the proposal-based idea, it'd be even more to do, so making these synonyms shouldn't be a problem IMO). PS: the SO search is terrible.