# What's the proper procedure when finding a synonym for a version specific tag?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

Today, I noticed that there exists a seperate tag for [ecmascript-harmony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-harmony) and [ecmascript-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6) on StackOverflow. As any JavaScript expert knows, ECMAScript 6 and ECMAScript Harmony are both synonyms for the lastest version of ECMAScript, aka [ECMAScript 2015 (6th Edition)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/ECMAScript_6_support_in_Mozilla).

As my score for both tags is `+5`, I wanted to suggest one as a synonym of the other, but no matter which of these tags I picked, I got the following error message when trying to suggest the other as a synonym :

[image]

Can anyone explain the logic behind this behavior? Or - more importantly - can anyone explain what's the proper procedure in thise case?

I suppose I could / should contact a moderator to make make [ecmascript-harmony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-harmony) the synonym of [ecmascript-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6), but what is the proper channel for this specific context?

---

#### Update :

From [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#Versions) :

> There are six editions of ECMA-262 published. Work on version 6 of the
> standard, codenamed "Harmony", was finalized in June 2015. [...] As
> the first “ECMAScript Harmony” specification, [ECMAScript 6] is also
> known as “ES6 Harmony”.

From [**the MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/ECMAScript_6_support_in_Mozilla) :

> ECMAScript 2015 (6th Edition) is the current version of the ECMAScript
> Language Specification standard. Commonly referred to as "ES6", it
> defines the standard for the JavaScript implementation in
> SpiderMonkey, the engine used in Firefox and other Mozilla
> applications.
>
> Code-named "ES.next" or "Harmony", the first working draft (based on
> ECMAScript 5.1) was published on July 12, 2011 as "ES.next".

From Leanpub's [**Understanding Ecmascript 6**](https://leanpub.com/understandinges6/read) :

> In 2008, Brendan Eich, the creator of JavaScript, announced that TC-39
> would focus its efforts on standardizing ECMAScript 3.1. They would
> table the major syntax and feature changes of ECMAScript 4 until after
> the next version of ECMAScript was standardized, and all members of
> the committee would work to bring the best pieces of ECMAScript 3.1
> and 4 together after that point into an effort initially nicknamed
> ECMAScript Harmony.
>
> ECMAScript 3.1 was eventually standardized as the fifth edition of
> ECMA-262, also described as ECMAScript 5. The committee never released
> an ECMAScript 4 standard to avoid confusion with the now-defunct
> effort of the same name. Work then began on ECMAScript Harmony, with
> ECMAScript 6 being the first standard released in this new
> “harmonious” spirit.
>
> ECMAScript 6 reached feature complete status in 2015 was formally
> dubbed “ECMAScript 2015” (though this text still refers to it as
> ECMAScript 6, the name most familiar to developers).

So, while ES-6 and ES Harmony aren't *literal* synonyms, both terms are so closely related they're used interchangeably by the vast majority of JS programmers out there because ECMAScript 6. IMO that makes them far more deserving of a status as tag synonyms than the vast majority of tag synonym definitions I've stumbled upon so far.

Comment: Meta is the correct channel. Now just lean back and wait for a mod to save the day...

Comment: Partial duplicate: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283398/retag-ecmascript-harmony-into-ecmascript-6

Comment: @TinyGiant : So if this problem has been known since Jan 13 '15, why has it still not been fixed? I can't think of a case where two tags are more obviously synonyms of each other than that of [tag:ecmascript-harmony] and [tag:ecmascript-6].

Comment: Bad tagging, it is tagged as a retag-request instead of a synonym-request.

Comment: @TinyGiant : Fixed that :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> As any JavaScript expert knows, ECMAScript 6 and ECMAScript Harmony are both synonyms for the lastest version of ECMAScript

Um, [no, they're not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21582553/1048572).

[ecmascript-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6) should only be used for features that were really introduced in that version of the spec. The term "harmony proposal" refers to others than that, it's more akin to what is known as "ES-next" these days. Admittedly, the tag [ecmascript-harmony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-harmony) could use some clean-up, but it's not a synonym.

---

Even if many programmers use the term interchangeably - and they *are* interchangeable applied to ES6 features, given that "Harmony" encompasses ES6 - we should not make them synonyms imo. We could equally well synonymise it with ES7 or one of the other coming versions.

And before deciding on anything, we should reach a consensus about how we want to tag javascript questions in general. There's the basic ES5.1 that most of the questions can be answered with, and which is implemented in all relevant engines. It does not need explicit tagging any more, and comments that some things might work differently in old IEs are getting more and more rare.

But with everything else, we do have a problem. The JS community is super excited about and super fast at adopting new features. ES Harmony has boot loads of interesting proposals, yet standardisation and implementation can't catch up with them. People are using transpilers anyway, and nothing is quicker enabled than an experimental plugin. We are getting dozens of questions about these *proposed* features on StackOverflow, but how should we tag them? We don't know in what spec version they will end up, or whether at all. For ES6, which is finalised now, this is easy. Still we've got lots of questions from the pre-finalisation era, which are possibly mistagged or whose answers might even be obsolete already. Does anyone want to clean up?
And it's worse with ES7. Not only do many people confuse it with ES6 ("*stage-0-proposal, works in babel, that's ES6, right?*", "*I've seen this syntax, why can't I get it to work in ES6?*"), but even when the difference is noted it just gets tagged with ES7 which is the "next" release. Everything that's on the standards track. But as we [learned recently](https://esdiscuss.org/notes/2016-01/2016-01-27.md), (probably) only two of the proposed features will really make it into the ES2016 revision of the spec. Now what are we going to do with the SO questions, retag most of them to ES8?

OK, this is a rant, and I know it. I can see a problem here, but I don't know a proper solution either. And whatever would be a proper way to solve it, is probably too much effort to be worth it. Most of us won't care enough. Do you? Propose a solution, and when it's good, I'll help you where I can.
A synonym request for [ecmascript-harmony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-harmony) may or may not be part of this unknown solution, I don't know (but believe not). Please don't do anything about this before having a solution in mind.

Comment: See the "update" at the bottom of my question

Comment: @JohnSlegers your update shows that, historically, "Harmony" and "ES-6" have been used interchangeably, including by the committee involved in writing the standards. So what? They're not used interchangeably *now*. Do you think we should synonymise `ES.next` to `ES-6`, too, now that it refers to the in-progress ES-7, just because when the term *first appeared* it meant ES-6? If not, why does it make any sense to do so with Harmony? The further into the future we get, the more absurd and perverse such a synonym will seem in retrospect.

Comment: @MarkAmery : Oh well, I made my point. If you guys don't agree with me on my position, that's fine. I honestly don't care enough about this to waste any more of my precious time on it.

Comment: @JohnSlegers: *I honestly don't care enough* - exactly, we don't either, and I believe that's reason enough not to synonymise it.

Comment: @Bergi : *I believe that's reason enough not to synonymise it* - That's a very strange reason, IMO, but... you're the boss!